# Как изменить форму кнопки в делфи

Tags: windows, delphi

Как изменить форму кнопки в делфи с прямоугольника до 6 угольника?

Comment: Какая целевая ОС, какая графическая библиотека (VCL/FMX) ?

Comment: я на 10 нужно к 7 а вот библеотека не подключена и я незнаю какая лучше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно копать в сторону SetWindowRgn. Например, так (код не оптимизирован, можно сделать кнопку покрасивее, но это уже тонкости, которые нужно отработать):

```
var
  pp: array[0..5] of TPoint;
  butt:HRGN;
  bx,by:integer;

<...>

  bx:=Button2.width; // у существующей кнопки получаем ширину и высоту
  by:=Button2.Height;
  // генерируем шестиугольник, я руководствуюсь банальной геометрией
  // кстати, можно даже и звезду сделать
  pp[0].X:=0;
  pp[0].Y:=by div 2;
  pp[1].X:= bx div 3;
  pp[1].y:=0;
  pp[2].X:= 2*pp[1].X;
  pp[2].Y:=0;
  pp[3].x:=bx-1;
  pp[3].y:=by div 2;
  pp[4].X:=pp[2].X;
  pp[4].y:=by-1;
  pp[5].x:=pp[1].x;
  pp[5].y:=by-1;
  // создаем регион из полигона
  butt:=CreatePolygonRgn(pp,6,WINDING);
  // применяем на существующий TControl, конкретно к Button2
  SetWindowRgn(Button2.Handle,butt,False);
```